# What is the command or script to add a part of folder name of that folder's filename?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, execute-command, batch-rename

Suppose I have folder structure like below

```
01. folder1
  |- 1. video1
  |- 2. video2
  |- 3. video3

02. folder2
  |- 1. photo1
  |- 2. photo2

03. folder3
  |- 1. doc1
  |- 2. doc2
```

Now I want to rename those files as below

```
01 folder1
  |- 01 1. video1
  |- 01 2. video2
  |- 01 3. video3

02 folder2
  |- 02 1. photo1
  |- 02 2. photo2

03 folder3
  |- 03 1. doc1
  |- 03 2. doc2
```

Which means I want to add first **3 character** (or any character) of folder name before its own filename (like batch rename).

So what is the command/script to rename it automatically like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a python script that is nearly similar to this problem.
So I modified the script as per my need.

This solve the exact problem which I am looking for.

```
python3 rename.py "/parent/dir/path"
```

```py
# filename is rename.py(save the file)
import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for f in files:
        shutil.move(root+"/"+f, root+"/"+root.split("/")[-1][0:3]+f)
```

If it shows permission problem, then run

```
sudo chmod +x rename.py
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Study `man find` and *(you might even google for examples)*
2. make it produce a list of "paths" enclosed in quotes[1] to the files you wish to change.
3. Then either use a text editor or continue hacking the find parameters, to create the names to change into, in a separate second column,
4. then add `mv`  (note space) at the beginning of each line
5. now either save the list as a text file and do `source name-of-file`, or alternatively pipe it to `bash`

Good luck.

*[1]  As you have spaces in your file and folder names*

Comment: Thanks @Hannu. I have found the solution with python script. Also I have revised find command. Thanks for your recommendation.